# Slice a list for a new column in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I am having a data.table with a tab separated string that I want to separate into new columns. However, if I slice by index, I just get the first element of the first row for every field. How do I do this?

```
library(data.table)
a <- c("feature1\titem1\titem2")
dt1 <- data.table(a)
a <- c("feature2\titem3\titem4")
dt2 <- data.table(a)
dt <- rbindlist(list(dt1, dt2))
dt[, split := mapply(str_split, a, "\t", n = 2)]
# how to get a feature column from that?
```

Comment: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html provides one method

Comment: You're looking for `tstrsplit`, e.g. `dt[, tstrsplit(a, '\t')]`

Comment: But `tstrsplit` does not have an option to only split on the first occurrence like `str_split`, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution with `transpose`:

```
dt[, transpose(stringr::str_split(a,"\t"))]
         V1     V2     V3
     <char> <char> <char>
1: feature1  item1  item2
2: feature2  item3  item4
```

Comment: with `dt[, transpose(stringr::str_split(a, "\t", n = 2))]` it works. Thanks for that :).